# My node app becomes slow even after increased the ram size

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, sequelize.js, node-debugger

The node app that am working becomes very slow and not even responding sometimes. While checking the logs I found that there was a problem with the memory. My app uses all 1400 ram space, then i searched for the solution and found to increase the memory so i increased the max space to 6gb ram, but still the app hits 6 gb and get hanged for period of time then restarts. Which makes my app very slow. Is there any way to solve this problem like clearing the memory or some other solution to make it fast.

Note: am using sequelize queries for sql, I'm not sure whether the problem is because of that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Android memory management is a whole study of its own. But it sounds like a memory leak if you're not using incredible amounts of memory.

Comment: Use heap snapshots to determine what is using all the memory and go from there.

Comment: This is certainly a memory leak, try using `memwatch-next` package to figure out what is going on